# Hypothesis testing with significance level

Tags: statistics, hypothesis-testing

Is the chance of hypertony is the same in normal and overweighted population?
How can we decide it using the following evidences with significance level α = 0.01? Out of 4200 normal patients 792, while out of 1000 overweighted ones 249 suffer of hypertony. Next decide, whether the overweight increases the chance of hypertony, significantly.

To be honest, I have no idea with the above problem? I was wondering if someone can help me? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try creating a hypothesis for the difference in proportions: I'll supply a vague outline but you should use correct notation and terms for your hypothesis test.

Null: The chance of getting Hypertony is the same between a normal and overweight population OR $$\text{$\mu $o}=\text{$\mu $n}$$

Alternative: being overweight increases the chance of hypertony OR $$\text{$\mu $o}>\text{$\mu $n}$$

*** SIDE NOTE: I should have used "P-hat" and not "M" because we are using proportions and not means/averages**

Find the proportion of normal and overweight patients who suffer from hypertony. This is just p = x/n

```
  x1 = 792
  x2 = 249
  n1 = 4200
  n2 = 1000
  p1 = .18857
  p2 = .249
```

**I really should have rounded p1 to .189**, but anyways *Can you implement these values in a ti-83 calculator yourself?*

Heres how to do it brute force by hand:

$$\text{upper}=.06043 + 2.575 \sqrt{\frac{(1-\text{p1}) \text{p1}}{\text{n1}}+\frac{(1-\text{p2}) \text{p2}}{\text{n2}}}$$

$$\text{lower}=.06043 - 2.575 \sqrt{\frac{(1-\text{p1}) \text{p1}}{\text{n1}}+\frac{(1-\text{p2}) \text{p2}}{\text{n2}}}$$

$$=0.02194,0.09892$$

***NOTE this does not supply a p-value but since the whole interval is positive and since we used overweight-normal, then this is evidence that there is a higher chance of having hypertony if overweight.. Only a graphing calculator or other statistical software will supply a P-value***

OR use statistical software such as R.

```
 prop.test(x=c(249,792), n=c(1000,4200), conf.level = .99, alternative = "greater")
```

2-sample test for equality of proportions with continuity correction

```
 data:  c(249, 792) out of c(1000, 4200)
 X-squared = 18.045, df = 1, p-value = 1.079e-05
 alternative hypothesis: greater
 99 percent confidence interval:
 0.02503623 1.00000000
 sample estimates:
 prop 1    prop 2 
 0.2490000 0.1885714
```

With P-value <.0001 you can safely reject the null hypothesis and conclude that being overweight does increase the chance of hypertony

I hope this helps..